# Understanding notation logic (from a BCS learning resource book)

Tags: logic, logical-operators, notation

Im currently learning about notation logic as part of a software development course im partaking in. One of the learning resources gives an example that i dont quite understand and would like some assistance explaining it please.

The notation logic example for a simple scoring system is as follows:

```
if ¬(score < 51 V score > 80)
```

For score is equal to 85 the example then gives this evaluation:

```
if ¬(true V score > 80)
if ¬(true V true)
if ¬(true)
if false
```

I dont understand how in the second step of the evaluation that both are true (true V true).

Any assistance will be greatly welcomed.

Comment: This seems plain wrong. The result is correct but for `score = 85` the expression `score < 51` will be `false`. So the first step would be `if ¬(false V score > 80)` and the second one `if ¬(false V true)`. The end result is the same, though. Perhaps it's a misprint - either they meant `score < 51` to be something else that resolves to `true`, or meant to use `false` for its result.

Answer (score 0):

If im undertanding this excersise correctly:

Im guessing you dont understand how it gets from:

```
if ¬(true V score > 80)->
->if ¬(true V true)->
->if ¬(true)->
->if false
```

1. For a score of 85 (score > 80 = true)
2. TRUE U TRUE = TRUE ( im guessing the V its U that means union,the union of trues equals true)
3. ¬ : this symbol means negation so the negation of true its false.

I recomend to take a look to algebraic expressions.

Comment: The V is the notation for the OR operator...which is what is confusing me, how can both sides be true...?

Comment: Given if¬(score < 51 V score > 80) on a score of 85 it should be: if¬(false V true) -> if¬(true) -> If false

Comment: That is what i thought however the example in the book, gives the correct answer to be what i first stated:  if ¬(true V true)